# iOS UITextField value without tapping on RETURN button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Is it possible to take UITextField value without tapping *RETURN* button?. If I type something in ***LOGIN UITextField*** and then tap on ***PASSWORD UITextField***, it looks like LOGIN value is empty, however if I type something in LOGIN, and then tap RETURN everything's fine.

Without tapping on RETURN
http://gyazo.com/2ca0f263275fd65ae674233f34d90280

With tapping on RETURN
http://gyazo.com/9ccc39ba7080b6b6344454ec757d3c0f

Here's my code:

**TextInputTableViewCell.m**

```
@implementation TextInputTableViewCell

-(void)configureWithDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self.cellInfoDictionary = dictionary;

    NSString *title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *imageName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"imageName"];
    UIColor *color = [dictionary objectForKey:@"bgColor"];
    BOOL secureTextEntry = [dictionary objectForKey:@"secure"];

    self.myTextField.placeholder = title;
    self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = color;
    self.myTextField.secureTextEntry = secureTextEntry;

    self.myTextField.delegate = self;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    if (textField.text)
    {
        [self.cellInfoDictionary setObject:textField.text
                                    forKey:@"value"];
    }

    return NO;
}

@end
```

**LoginViewController.m**

```
@interface LoginViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NewRestHandlerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *datasource;

@end

static NSString *textInputCellIdentifier = @"textInputCellIdentifier";
static NSString *buttonCellIdentifier = @"buttonCellIdentifier";


@implementation LoginViewController
{
  NSString *email;
  NSString *password;
  NewRestHandler *restHandler;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  if ([defaults boolForKey:@"logged"])
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Logged"
                              sender:self];
  [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([TextInputTableViewCell class])
                                             bundle:nil]
       forCellReuseIdentifier:textInputCellIdentifier];

  [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([ButtonTableViewCell class])
                                             bundle:nil]
       forCellReuseIdentifier:buttonCellIdentifier];

  restHandler = [[NewRestHandler alloc] init];
  restHandler.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSString *cellIdentifier = [dictionary objectForKey:@"cellIdentifier"];

  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(configureWithDictionary:)])
  {
    [cell performSelector:@selector(configureWithDictionary:)
               withObject:dictionary];
  }

  return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return self.datasource.count;
}

...

- (NSArray *)datasource
{
  if (!_datasource)
  {
    NSMutableArray* datasource = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];

    NSMutableDictionary* loginDictionary = @{@"cellIdentifier": textInputCellIdentifier,
                                             @"title": @"Login",
                                             @"imageName": @"edycja02.png",
                                             @"bgColor": [UIColor whiteColor],
                                             }.mutableCopy;

    NSMutableDictionary* passwordDictionary = @{@"cellIdentifier": textInputCellIdentifier,
                                                @"title": @"Password",
                                                @"imageName": @"edycja03.png",
                                                @"bgColor": [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                @"secure": @YES,
                                                }.mutableCopy;

    NSMutableDictionary* loginButtonDictionary = @{@"cellIdentifier": buttonCellIdentifier,
                                                   @"title": @"Login",
                                                   @"imageName": @"logowanie01.png",
                                                   @"bgColor": [UIColor colorWithRed:88/255.0 green:88/255.0 blue:90/255.0 alpha:1],
                                                   @"textColor": [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                   }.mutableCopy;

    NSMutableDictionary* facebookLoginButtonDictionary = @{@"cellIdentifier": buttonCellIdentifier,
                                                           @"title": @"Login with Facebook",
                                                           @"imageName": @"logowanie02.png",
                                                           @"bgColor": [UIColor colorWithRed:145/255.0 green:157/255.0 blue:190/255.0 alpha:1],
                                                           @"textColor": [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                           }.mutableCopy;

    NSMutableDictionary* signUpButtonDictionary = @{@"cellIdentifier": buttonCellIdentifier,
                                                    @"title": @"Sign up",
                                                    @"imageName": @"logowanie03.png",
                                                    @"bgColor": [UIColor colorWithRed:209/255.0 green:210/255.0 blue:212/255.0 alpha:1],
                                                    @"textColor": [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                    }.mutableCopy;

    [datasource addObject:loginDictionary];
    [datasource addObject:passwordDictionary];
    [datasource addObject:loginButtonDictionary];
    [datasource addObject:facebookLoginButtonDictionary];
    [datasource addObject:signUpButtonDictionary];

    _datasource = datasource;
  }
  return _datasource;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (indexPath.row == 2)
  {
    email = [self.datasource[0] valueForKey:@"value"];
    password = [self.datasource[1] valueForKey:@"value"];

    NSLog(@"Email: %@", email);
    NSLog(@"Password: %@", password);

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    if (textField.text)
    {
        [self.cellInfoDictionary setObject:textField.text
                                    forKey:@"value"];
    }

    return NO;
}
```

to:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if (textField.text)
    {
        [self.cellInfoDictionary setObject:textField.text
                                    forKey:@"value"];
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if (textField.text)
    {
        [self.cellInfoDictionary setObject:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]
                                    forKey:@"value"];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

everything should work as expected

Comment: I've made changes to source code. Please check now.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this...

```
 -(void)textFieldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
     {
        if(textfield == Password)
    {
            if(login.text.length isEqualtoString:@"")
        {
             //Alert show that login text should not be empty or do your code
         }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
```

}

These are `UITextFieldDelegate` methods. But there should be a better way than changing the dictionary key each time user presses a key. Set `textField` object as a `property` of `TextInputTableViewCell` and reach that `textField` object in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Note : `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` will have the text before adding last action. If you pressed "a" for example, when flow enters this function it `textField.text` won't have it. Please see the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you tap the textfield from login to password, in the textFieldDidBeginEditing method, save the text entered in login text field to an NSString or NSUserDefaults as per your wish.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

 if(textfield == passwordTextField )
{
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",loginTextField.text]forKey:@"LOGINCREDENTIALS"];
}
}
```

This will automatically save your userName string into userDefaults as soon as to tap the Password textfield.

you can access the stored string from the userDefaults as:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"LOGINCREDENTIALS"];
```

Hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible,you can perform

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

`if (textField == your textfield here)
{

if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
{

//perform anything here

}
}
}`
```

here when you'll click on other textfield, it will check your present textfield whether it is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Use  shouldChangeCharactersInRange as this method calls every time you tapped on text field:-

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range   replacementString:(NSString *)string {
 NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
 //Your Code here
     return YES;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are delegate methods by which you can do this

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range   replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{

 NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);

 return YES;
}
```